# Connecting to sql server on windows machine from a .net app on docker container on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows, docker

We have SQL server 2014  running on the Windows machine. We have a microservice developed using .net. This microservice deployed using a docker container on the Linux machine. To connect from the microservice to the SQL server, we used integrated security = true in the connection string of the microservice.But this is not working. Can someone help us resolve this issue? We don't want to use the user name and password in the connection string.

Comment: How is it not working?  Can you include the actual error message you're getting in the question?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

Answer (score 0):

What is connection string here ?
If it is a string parameter you are trying to pass inside in your application as username and password then below solution will work:

Run you container with env variables ( env variables will be your credentials)

ex:

docker run -d --name ${processName} --env-file /opt/properties.file -p ${exposePort}:${servicePort} ${dockerRegistry}/${projectName}/${serviceName}:${imageTagName}

properties.file here will be your connection string stored on your machine

Comment: This is the sample connection string for sql server "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;"